# Sort gridview with data from 1:n relationship from junction table

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

i have a 3 table

1. product_tbl                // hold product data
2. specification_tbl         // hold all type of specification  that my product can have
3. product_specification_tbl   // (kind of Junction table)hold each Product Specification Value based on  [$name => $value]format.
   relation between product_tbl and product_specification_tbl is 1:n

   | product-id | specification-id | name | value |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 10 | Tire Width | 250 |
   | 1 | 11 | Aspect Ratio | 50 |
   | 1 | 12 | Rim Size | 16 |
   | 2 | 10 | Tire Width | 195 |
   | 2 | 11 | Aspect Ratio | 70 |
   | 2 | 12 | Rim Size | 14 |

now i need combine this specification as follow:

```
| product_id | [Tire Width]/[Aspect Ratio]R[Rim Size] |
|            |              as Tire Size              |
|------------|----------------------------------------|
|     1      |               250/50R16                |
|     2      |               195/70R14                |
```

so now i have need to have new  column in gridView  with ability of sorting based on new combined value  (Tire Size Column)

problem is that sorting generally perform on the column but here i need to Sort my products based on a specification value (tire width, aspect ratio, rim size and ... )that is stored in database junction table rows not column.

i think i should first create  temporary table that holds  specifications indexed by product id and store each data in separate column.
or i don't know maybe there is another way?!?

either way i don't know how to do it!!!

i will be glad if someone can help me on this topic.
thank you.

<---- GridView Code -------------------------------------------------->

```php
<?php
           echo GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

                    [
                        'attribute' => 'brand.name_en',
                        'label' => 'Brand'

                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'family.name_en',
                        'label' => 'Model',
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'productTreadWidth.value_en',
                        'label' => Yii::t('app' , 'Tire Width'),
                        'content' => function($model){
                            return $model->productTreadWidth['value_en'];
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'productAspectRatio.value_en',
                        'label' => Yii::t('app' , 'Aspect Ratio'),
                        'content' => function($model){
                            return $model->productAspectRatio['value_en'];
                        }
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'productDiameter.value_en',
                        'label' => Yii::t('app' , 'Diameter'),
                        'content' => function($model){
                            return $model->productDiameter['value_en'];
                        }
                    ],                    
                   'name_en',
                   'product_id',
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
```

<---- Relation Code -------------------------------------------------->

```php
<?php
 public function getProductTreadWidth()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 2]);
    }
    public function getProductAspectRatio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 3]);
    }
    public function getProductDiameter()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductSpecification::className(), ['product_id' => 'product_id'])->where(['specification_id' => 5]);
    }
?>
```

> now new problem rise :D i can sort separatley by Tread Width | Aspect
> Ratio | Diameter
>
> but i need all this 3 column sort ASC or DESC at the same time.

Database Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qHx5.png)

> select Query Result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Nip.png)

> Column i need perform sort on it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJWoB.png)

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/sort-gridview-with-data-from-1-n-relationship-from-junction-table/134403?u=nareka88

Comment: Initially paste some code what you've done so far so we can help adjust your query. Nobody will write this query for you.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco  hi, i just wanna know is there any way to do it or not?  and i upload some database tables, GridView and wanted query result images. Thank you.

Comment: Have you try to make a raw sql query to get desired result? Posting photos is not a good way to communicate here. There is a `code sample` button in the edit area which allow you to paste a sample code.

Comment: Because you are going to use it in grid view, you will always sort based on only one column. So, it might be better to construct join with required rows from `product_specification_tbl` based on parameter used for sorting instead of building some complex generic query to handle all possible sortings. Something like `... LEFT JOIN product_specifcation_tbl order ON (product.id = order.product_id AND order.specification_id = <required specification for sorting>) ... ORDER BY order.value ASC`.

Comment: As for combined values, you can do multiple joins and then sort by multiple columns like this: `LEFT JOIN product_specifcation_tbl order1 ON (product.id = order1.product_id AND order1.specification_id = <width spec id>) LEFT JOIN product_specification_tbl order2 (product.id = order2.product_id AND order2.specification_id = <aspect ratio id>) ... ORDER BY order1.value ASC, order2.value ASC ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for sorting each value separately the above code will solve the problem.

for sorting all value together after all searches and tests i just find a way.
now i can sort many row value in gridView just by changein dataProvider query

```php
 'query' => Product::find()->select(['Group_concat({{%product_specification}}.value_en SEPARATOR "/") as size ' , '{{%product_specification}}.product_id'])->joinWith(['brand', 'family', $joinTable ], true, 'LEFT JOIN')->where(['availability_id' => 1])->andWhere('FIND_IN_SET(specification_id,"2,3,5")')->groupBy('product_id'),
```

it solve using
1)GROUPBY
2)GROUP_CONCAT
3)FIND_IN_SET

Thanks to all those who read the issue and tried to solve it.